# Writing Rails on multiple Os (windows and osx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, macos, git, heroku

I have have to work on a windows machine at work but have a mac at home. All of my rails code is written on the mac which is using RVM and deploying to heroku using GIT.

However I want to start working on the code on a windows machine (code held in dropbox and synced automatically)

I remember that line endings caused hell in git when I used to write python code... What are the requirements to be able to right RoR using two different operating systems?

Comment: As the editor use Sublime Text 2. It has awesome features, supports TM's bundles, can be easily extended and integrated with with Git.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure git to convert line endings to one or the other upon committing: http://help.github.com/line-endings/

When you are describing paths, be sure to use built in methods for constructing them OS independently, like `File.join`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the core.autocrlf feature.
From the manual

> core.autocrlf
>          Setting this variable to "true" is almost the same as setting the text attribute to "auto" on all files except that text files are
>   not guaranteed to be normalized: files that contain CRLF in the
>   repository will not be touched. Use this setting if you want to have
>   CRLF line endings in your working directory even though the repository
>   does not have normalized line endings. This variable can be set to
>   input, in which case no output conversion is performed.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

So, In your windows machine, set this feature to true, which means,

During commit, your line endings will automatically be changed to LF and when you checkout your local files will have Windows' line endings (i.e., CRLF)

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

In your non-Windows machine, set this to input, which means

Don't do any conversions, I'm not prone to any line ending changes

Answer (score 0):

Why not configure heroku on your work machine instead?  You already have version control (git) to take care of syncing and sharing your app.